# How To echo a line break in the browser?

Tags: php

I dont know how to echo a new line in PHP. I have tried `echo "\n"` but it does not work.

I want to echo new lines in the following code.

**Code**:

```
if (file_exists($fName)) {
   echo "CreationTime: ".$CreationTime.
        "CurrentTime: ".$CurrentTime.
        "after ".($fLifeTime)." Days from Creation: ".$fAge;
   }
```

Comment: Use "<br/>" since you're echoing the content to your browser. :)

Comment: It is `echo "\n"` like you tried. Do you mean you didn't see a new line in your *browser*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - how to create a newline character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IF you are looking this output from a browser, you must use `<br />` tag or, put `<pre>` before your echo.

For new line 
 example.

```
if (file_exists($fName)) {
   echo "CreationTime: ".$CreationTime. "<br />".
        "CurrentTime: ".$CurrentTime. "<br />" .
        "after ".($fLifeTime)." Days from Creation: ".$fAge;
   }
```

pre example

```
 if (file_exists($fName)) {
      echo "<pre>";
       echo "CreationTime: ".$CreationTime. PHP_EOL .
            "CurrentTime: ".$CurrentTime. PHP_EOL .
            "after ".($fLifeTime)." Days from Creation: ".$fAge;
       }
```

Comment: +1 for the pre suggestion. But if you can help it, only use pre when using a print command

Comment: Thank you, I will write new example for EOL.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
if (file_exists($fName)) {
    echo "CreationTime: ".$CreationTime.
    "<br />CurrentTime: ".$CurrentTime.
    "<br />after ".($fLifeTime)." Days from Creation: ".$fAge;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this:--

```
if (file_exists($fName)) {
   echo "CreationTime: ".$CreationTime.
        "CurrentTime: ".$CurrentTime.
        "after ".($fLifeTime)." Days from Creation: ".$fAge;
echo "<br/>"; //break to new line.
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) and [nl2br()](http://php.net/nl2br)?

```
if (!file_exists($fName)) {
    $info = "CreationTime: " . $CreationTime . PHP_EOL .
        "CurrentTime: ". $CurrentTime . PHP_EOL .
        "after ". ($fLifeTime)." Days from Creation: " . $fAge;

    echo nl2br($info);
}
```