# Carriage return and line feed

Tags: php, carriage-return, file-writing, linefeed

I got stuck with carriage return and line feed problem. When I run my script it shows CR,LF inside double quote of last field and there is another LF after than, realistically CR,LF should be outside of double quote of text and there shouldn't be another LF. Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
$jobno = 5285;

$directory = "../CSV/";
$filename = $jobno.'.csv';
if( is_dir($directory) === false )
{
   mkdir($directory); // Create new directory 

}
$newFname = $directory.$filename;

$file = fopen($newFname, 'w');


$jobdetails="2,000 Items Supplied";
$customerName="Snap Pitzaa Ltd";
$workflow="CSV_wise";
$jobqty=50;
$filepath="Data/Snap Pitzaa/design.pdf \r\n";

$data = array(
    array($jobno, $jobdetails, $customerName, $workflow, $jobqty, $filepath),
    array('Data 21', 'Data 22', 'Data 23', 'Data 24', 'Data 25', 'Data 26'),

);

// save each row of the data
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    fputcsv($file, $row);
}

// Close the file
fclose($file);
```

I've tried all the things like single quote, outside doubleheader of `$filepath` but none of this is working. Here is output in notepad++

[image]

Comment: lookout for unicode

Comment: Wouldn't changing `$filepath="Data/Snap Pitzaa/design.pdf \r\n";` to `$filepath="Data/Snap Pitzaa/design.pdf";` fix it, i.e. remove the explicit CR/LF you are including within the string?

Comment: thanks for suggestion, can you plz read my below comment cos both of you suggest me same thing and in certain way its correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just given myself an introduction to PHP (I've never used it before), I think the following code will correctly write a CR/LF to the end of each record you write:

```
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    // write out the normal output, with a LF automatically created by fputcsv
    fputcsv($file, $row);
    // move the file pointer back to the end of the data
    fseek($file, -1, SEEK_CUR); 
    // write out a CR/LF
    fwrite($file, "\r\n");
}
```

---

You should also change

```
$filepath="Data/Snap Pitzaa/design.pdf \r\n";
```

to

```
$filepath="Data/Snap Pitzaa/design.pdf";
```

as there shouldn't be a CR/LF **inside** that field.

Comment: Thanks @Jesse Bunch you both showed me right thing and it solved my problem. Thanks guys, spend almost 3 hours to figure this out and without your help wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

`fputcsv` is terminated by a newline ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)). Therefore, you don't need to add the `\r\n` to your `$filepath` variable.

This:

`$filepath="Data/Snap Pitzaa/design.pdf \r\n";`

Should be changed to this:

`$filepath='Data/Snap Pitzaa/design.pdf';`

That should remove the "CRLF" and move the quote to where you want it.

**Edit 12/13/16**

From your comment, it sounds like you need to replace the unix-style line endings that `fputcsv` outputs by default with windows-style line endings. The most elegant way I've seen to do this was from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080456/fputcsv-and-newline-codes):

```
// Writes an array to an open CSV file with a custom end of line.
//
// $fp: a seekable file pointer. Most file pointers are seekable, 
//   but some are not. example: fopen('php://output', 'w') is not seekable.
// $eol: probably one of "\r\n", "\n", or for super old macs: "\r"
function fputcsv_eol($fp, $array, $eol) {
  fputcsv($fp, $array);
  if("\n" != $eol && 0 === fseek($fp, -1, SEEK_CUR)) {
    fwrite($fp, $eol);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse for your answer. If I use just string, line feed added automatically at the end and this is correct but this new generated file picked up automatically by other program (which I don't have control) once it goes in CSV folder and it gives error without CR and LF at the end and if that file path is not surrounded by double quote.

Comment: @katya.lee see my edit. I think I know what you're asking for.

Comment: or to just add the \r to it, just use `if (fseek($fp, -1, SEEK_CUR) === 0) fwrite($fp, "\r\n");`

Answer (score -1):

I've been trying to find this answer and after finding multiple pages that say "\r\n" or something similar. None of which was working I might add.

I found a couple quick posts that said `<br>` works... and it does.

```
<?php
// prints e.g. 'Current PHP version: ?.?.?'
echo "Current Browser version: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "<br>";
echo 'Current Server software version: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] . "<br>";
echo "Current PHP info:" . "<br>" ;
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

Just adding the `echo "<br>";` to a separate line works as does `. "<br>";` to the end of the line.

Comment: This question is/was about adding a CRLF to a file. You seem to need to add it to the output in a browser, which is different, see: [How To echo a line break in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635539/how-to-echo-a-line-break-in-the-browser)