# Unable to use metacharacters in php

Tags: php

i'm using metacharacter in a simple php code, but it is now showing **Second line of text** into a new line.

```
echo "First line of text \r\n Second line of text";
```

I know Unix based systems use just a "\n". But as i'm on Windows 7, so i am using "/r/n"

Comment: I assure you it is.  You're probably just looking at it in a web browser with the HTML content type set (default), where whitespace doesn't matter like you think it does.  (Try a `<br/>`.)

Comment: @user170654 : list of answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character

Comment: @Brad yeah. i was looking at my browser. I figured out that it includes linebreak, tabs in the source code. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
echo nl2br("First line of text\n Second line of text");
```

[nl2br](https://www.php.net/nl2br) function

Or you can use [EOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128560/when-do-i-use-the-php-constant-php-eol) in php

Comment: No explanation?  They guy is new.  You should explain your answer.

Comment: I don't see the reason for a down-voting, given the above code works

Comment: yes I also agreed with @user007, there no reason for down voting.

Comment: I was writing the explanation,should havbe given me a chance,I am new too. Had to find the links.

Comment: @GunnerAziz Don't post then until you have an answer.  Your answer still doesn't explain what `nl2br()` does.  That's why I downvoted you, and yes this absolutely warrants a downvote in my opinion.  I gave you a chance... I read what you posted.  I also just read your recent edit.  Revise it again, and I'll read it again.  That's how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using other way with basic `HTML` tag `<br />`:

```
echo "First line of text" . "<br />" . "Second line of text";
```