# New line character php

Tags: php

I've been trying to echo a new line character but it hasn't worked. Each time I loop I would like to add break after each iteration.

```
foreach($result as $row){

        $node =  '{"author":"' . $row["name"] . '"},';
        echo "\n";

    }
```

This is what I have but it's still printing all in one line. Any Suggestions?

Comment: look at your HTML source; it's in there alright. Use a combination of - `<br>`. with that `\n` and it will show it to you on screen as well. `\n` alone only shows up as a new line if writing to a file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character

Comment: If you want a new line in a browser you have to use a break tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will surely work.

```
foreach($result as $row){
    $node =  '{"author":"' . $row["name"] . '"},';
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: It worked! thank you!

Comment: and what if they want to write to a file later on? that's a possibility. This for future readers to the question/answer.

Comment: yeah, but that situation was not stated in the question. If it was, I would have acted accordingly.