# Alternative of using <br> in several lines

Tags: php, html, css

I am required to copy and paste several codes on my websites and I just can't do it. the way I am doing it takes a bit more time. is there any alternative to do this more simply? I just need an option for inserting `<br>` in every line. What I am doing is this: inserting `<br>` in every line.

```
    <br>$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","learndb");
    <br>$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from admin where username = ?");
    <br>$stmt->bind_param("s",$first);
    <br>$stmt->execute();
    <br>$result=$stmt->get_result();    
    <br>$myrow=$result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\r\n` in a php echo.

See this post: [PHP - how to create a newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character)

Answer (score 0):

You can use \r \n....`echo '\r'`