# Display php query output to every new row

Tags: php

I have below code which gives output as a single line. Please help me to get array value to new row.
I have tried using `</br>` or `<br>` but no use.

Code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $string = "copy \\\\plm\\tt\\data\\";
}

$des=$_POST["tester"];
if($des=="") {
    // if ALL is selected in Dropdown box
    $res=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM workflow1");
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_row($res))
    {
        echo "$string$r[4]";
    }
}
```

Current output:

```
  copy \\plm\tt\data\event3copy \\plm\tt\data\event5copy \\plm\tt\data\event4
```

Desired output:

```
  copy \\plm\tt\data\event3
  copy \\plm\tt\data\event5
  copy \\plm\tt\data\event4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - how to create a newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Newline behavior depends on context

If you're trying to show this in HTML, add `<br>` tags. 
If you're trying to show newlines in raw-text, or CLI (console) output, use `"\n"`

```
while($r=mysqli_fetch_row($res))
{
    $newline = "\n";
    // $newline = "<br>";
    // $newline = "<br>\n";
    echo $string . $r[4] . $newline;
}
```

#### What does "newline" mean?

If you really want to know the basics of the crazy legacy from typewriters that is the source of this, see: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-great-newline-schism/

- Newline: start a new line of inline text or content.
- CR: carriage-return - can mean go to start of this line, or start a new line.
- LF: line-feed - start a new line.
- CRLF: combined of the two above.
- "\n": PHP double-quoted strings will turn this into a CRLF.
- BR: html "break" - html ignores whitespace (space, CR, LF, tab, etc.), thus the BR tag.

Comment: Thanks Tody, gives output as expected!

Comment: one more query, at starting of first line only there are 2 spaces. How can I remove them?

Comment: That means that your code, or the library it uses, is outputting or echoing space characters. You'll either have to find it, echo a newline before the code in my answer, or dive deep into IOStreams, and console control.

Comment: Just got rid of these spaces by adding new line before `if` condition. Thank you, Tony!

Answer (score 1):

your statement should looks like this

```
 echo $string . $r[4] . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks samehanwar, it also works fine that tool less code!

Comment: I completely agree, but please always try to include some explanation or context to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Add the tag below to get a new line in HTML

```
echo "$string$r[4]";
?><BR/><?php
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: Gives output like this:   `copy \\plm\tt\]data\event3<BR/>copy \\plm\tt\data\event5<BR/>copy \\plm\tt\data\event4`

Comment: try this, youll see something different on your page?  2 line loop