# How to stop terminal from starting on same line as output

Tags: php

I'm currently starting to learn php off of Laracasts, and I have a very basic issue. My code is the following:

```
    <?php 
    echo 'Hello World';
```

In the video, this exact code outputs "Hello World", and then starts the terminal prompt on a new line.
He doesn't use /n or any other new line code
I wrote this same code on Sublime Text. When I run this in terminal, the echo'd "Hello World" displays, but it is on the same line as the next terminal prompt.
However, if I run the exact same code in a different text editor(I tried Visual Studio Code next) the "Hello World" displays, but the terminal prompt starts on a new line.
Wondering why this is happening in Sublime Text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - how to create a newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238433/php-how-to-create-a-newline-character)

Comment: Different terminals have different setups. Some of them will automatically add a new line after input, or running a function. On a normal command line, it will not automatically add a new line.

Comment: Thanks! You were right, he is using a different terminal!

Answer (score 3):

You want to specify a new line character/carriage return.

In PHP you need to use double quotes like this: `echo "Hello World\n";`

more info on carriage returns here:
[\r\n, \r and \n what is the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-and-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them)

Windows and Linux both have their own interpretations, more information can be found in this [informative post](https://superuser.com/questions/374028/how-are-n-and-r-handled-differently-on-linux-and-windows).

Comment: Thanks! Weird, I am watching the laracast video for php learning, and he doesn't include the /n or the double quotes, yet it still outputs it that same way. Can you explain this?

Comment: Because on a terminal, the '\n'  represent a new line