# Remove empty space and carriage return from a string with ] at end and [ at the start of the next line

Tags: php, regex

I am relatively new to regular expressions. I just wanted to know that how to replace empty spaces or carriage return ( new line ) through `preg_replace` in php for this string:

```
[someshortcode]

[someshortcode]
```

The string has `]` at the end of one line and `[` at the new line. I want to remove any spaces/ characters be it `'\r'` ,`'\t'`, `'\n'`, empty spaces or any other character

output should be like this: `[someshortcode][someshortcode]`

Thanks

Comment: What is your current regex?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove new lines and returns from php string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986299/how-to-remove-new-lines-and-returns-from-php-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace("/\s/", '', $string);
```

You can learn more about the "\s" and others in **[Escape sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)**

**Update**:

I'd like to add an alternative with POSIX compliant regular expression, where you could use the following line, which by the way would also match the VT character (code 11):

```
$result = preg_replace("/[[:space:]]/", '', $string);
```

More about **[Character classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php#regexp.reference.character-classes)**

Comment: Just a notice - in his case it is job for `str_replace` as it will be faster.

Comment: @MarkS - I do agree. Still the author explicitly asked for **preg_replace**.

Comment: +1 Thanks mate for correcting me. I was in a false notion. Thanks once again. I deleted my answer ;)

Comment: @blue Thanks, that's what I was looking for. However your previous answer also worked fine for me.

Comment: @blue May I ask, why you're using `m (PCRE_MULTILINE)`, where anchors for str start/end also match the line start/end, which arent't used here.

Comment: @Jonny5 - you're right. /m has no effect, so its presence is useless, removing.